# Determine $\lim_{t→∞} \mathbb{P}_i(X_t = 0) $ for $i = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

Tags: markov-process, birth-death-process

I have this problem, I figured out the part **(a)** but I'm having a little trouble with part **(b)** if anyone can help me with that.

> Two repairmen serve three machines (that is, at most two machines can be under repair at the same time). The time until a particular machine needs repair is exponential with mean $1/3$ and independent of other repairs and failures. Each repair time is exponential with mean $1/2$ and independent of other repairs and failures. Let  $X_t$  be the number of machines under repair or needing repair at time $t$.
>
> (a) Determine the birth and death intensities of the birth and death process $(X_t)$, $t≥0$.
>
> (b) Determine $\lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{P}_i(X_t=0)$ for $i = 0,1,2,3$.

From a I got this matrix
$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
 -9 &  9  &  0  &  0  \\ 
  2 & -8  &  6  &  0  \\ 
  0 &  4  & -7  &  3  \\ 
  0 &  0  &  2  & -2
\end{bmatrix} $$
But I am not sure how to do **(b)**, I was trying to do $\lambda Q=0$ but I was not getting the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

From $\pi Q = 0$ we have
\begin{align}
-9\pi_0 + 2\pi_1 = 0\\
9\pi_0-8\pi_1+4\pi_2=0\\
6\pi_1-7\pi_2+2\pi_3=0\\
3\pi_2-2\pi_3=0
\end{align}
Note that this system of equations is linearly independent, since the right-hand side are all zero. So arbitrarily choose an equation to remove, and add the equation $\sum_{i=0}^3\pi_i=1$. This yields the solution
$$
\pi_0 = \frac8{179},\quad \pi_1 = \frac{36}{179},\quad \pi_2 = \frac{54}{179},\quad \pi_3 = \frac{81}{179}.
$$
Alternatively we could look at a row of $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{tG}$. But $e^{tG}$ is not trivial to compute, so using the relation $\pi Q=0$ is highly recommended.